# how to prevent php code to run when loading a page

Tags: php

Good day,

Although I'm an old programmer, I'm new to php, so I need help.

**Context**
1. I have a submit form with an update button. 
2. I have php code to insert records in a MySQL database.

**Problem**
1. When I first start the page, the php code runs.
2. When I refresh the page, the php code runs again.

**Code**

```
<!-- Button definition -->  
<input id="submit" type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="submit"     onclick="Update_MySQL()" /> 

<!-- Function to be executed by the onclick --> 
<script>
<?php 
function Update_MySQL() {
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$sql = "MYSQL UPDATE STRING" ;
$MY_CONNECTION->query($sql) ; 
}
}   
?>
</script>
```

**What I know**
1. PHP runs on server and javascript on the browser (client)
2. PHP delivers data to the server when the page is launched or refreshed

Can anyone help me on this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Please add complate code of page for better answers

Comment: You cannot execute a PHP function with Javascript's onclick event.

Comment: You can't call a PHP function from an `onclick()` like that....

Comment: You don't need the `onclick` attribute for the submit button. And if that's your code then nothing is wrong with it else edit your question with the detailed code

Comment: You should not name your submit button "submit" - may lead to javascript errors when using - and not check for the submit button as not all browsers send it if the form is submitted using the return/enter key.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent this when using the native html `<form action="form.php">` way, but there is a way around. After progressing your form, you can redirect using header() to another page (or even the same) with a GET-Redirection-Code (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)).

```
if (isset($_POST['field'])) {
    // progress data
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}
```

Another completely different but also working approach is to use javascript to submit your form data.